# Laravel: Pivot Table, ManytoMany

Tags: laravel, pivot, relationship

I have been stuck on this since May 2020. I don't know how to move forward with the project. Any link or guidance would be very much appreciated. I'm trying to create a very simple rental system.

I have a **Customer** table: id, Name, Barcode
Another one is **Item** table: id, Name, Barcode, OnLoan

I'm trying to create a Form where there is a search box for Customer and search box for the Items. When the customer barcode is found and item barcode is found, you can fill in the Date Loaned and Date Due and click submit.

In the Item table, the **OnLoan** needs to be set to 1.

How do we do this please? Any link or keywords to help me on my way would be really great.

I have been googling and found out about onetomany, manytomany, pivot, scope, repositories. It's very overwhelming, i'm trying to go over them one at a time.

Comment: Well, first of all, a `one-to-many` doesn't have a pivot table, so your title doesn't make a whole lot of sense. For your use case, you'd probably need a `loans` table, which is a pivot between Custom and Item (since it would have `custom_id` and `item_id`, and a due_date), which would make this a `many-to-many`, but you could add logic to prevent a pivot from being added if there's already a loan, etc etc. Your question is a bit broad though; you'll likely need to include what you've tried, and a specific error, etc.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Ok I will look into pivot tables and post what I’ve tried.

Comment: Sounds good! Best of luck, and don't hesitate to ask more questions :)